# Animate Custom Battery Fill Icon

Tags: javascript, user-interface, ionic-framework

I am using HTML, CSS and Javascript in a cross-platform Ionic mobile app. I want to create a "live" battery fill graphic, so a battery outline has an analogue (ish) fill which moves with the percentage charge.

I could obviously substitute the source image for a different picture every 5% etc. but this doesn't seem to be a great way of doing this. Is there a neater way using JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following to do this;

1. A couple of HTML containers to represent the battery outline and the battery charge.
2. Use javascript to manipulate the 'height' of the battery charge container

   `setInterval(function(){
     if(batteryPercentage <= 100){
       batteryInner.style.height = batteryPercentage + '%';
       batteryPercentage += 5;
     }
   }, 100)`
3. Use css transitions for the height on the battery charge container to animate the height change.

Quick and dirty example https://jsfiddle.net/r2unrg31/

### Updated Fiddle

Base on the comments, here's an updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r2unrg31/1/

Please note, you could neaten this up to include a border on top of the notch. Also note, the background color of the 'notches' will need to match the background color of your platform.

Comment: Nice! Is there a way of ensuring that the green bar doesn't go outside of the outline. I am thinking about the little bump you often get at the top middle of the battery icon. I could just have a white background on the battery outline, but then I need to ensure my platform's background color doesn't change

Comment: You could possibly split the battery container in to three elements, using two of them as blocks in the top left and top right with borders. Their background could be set to match your platform's background. I'll update the answer with an example of this.

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards See my updated answer. Although I don't know much about Ionic, you might me able to manage the colour changes (for platforms) with css, js and user agent sniffing/media queries.